# How to make GRASS 7 addon available in QGIS 2.12?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, windows-10

I stumbled across the GRASS-Tool [**`i.segment`**](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/i.segment.html) but could not find it in my QGIS processing toolbox. I found out that it is an addon for  GRASS 7 that I already installed in GRASS 7 standalone. How can I import Grass 7 into QGIS?

I installed the latest QGIS Version with the OSGeo4W installer and enabled Grass for installation. The thing is, that the OSGeo4W installation installed Grass 6.4.3 and not Grass 7.  I do know how to [configure external applications](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty.html) (I have already done this for Grass 6.4.3 and for OTB). I am wondering how it is possible to make GRASS 7 (tools and addons) available within the processing toolbox?

I updated Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Comment: Which operation system are you using?

Comment: I updated win 7 to win 10.

Answer (score 5):

Both QGIS and GRASS GIS are standalone applications which can be used on their own. QGIS is using some of the functionality from GRASS GIS through QGIS GRASS Plugin and through QGIS Processing. Each of these can support some of the tools available in GRASS GIS or somehow modifies their usage. In this context, the functions or tools in GRASS GIS are called modules. Not all these modules are supported by QGIS, either because they simply were not added to the list or QGIS is not able to accommodate their interface.

Both QGIS GRASS Plugin and QGIS Processing support both GRASS GIS 6 and 7. QGIS is currently transitioning from version 6 to 7, so the different distributions of QGIS can include different versions. The plugin or Processing can be configured to use one or the other once it is installed. In OSGeo4W, GRASS GIS 7 is currently probably in an advanced installation.

Some of the GRASS GIS modules are not part of the standard GRASS GIS installation and their are available in GRASS GIS Addons repository. You can install them in GRASS GIS using GUI or `g.extension` module. These cannot be used in QGIS because Processing nor the plugin (at least currently) support arbitrary modules, just the ones specified in QGIS. For example, `i.segment` was an addon at one point but now it is included in GRASS GIS directly. Some addons stay just addons.

If you want full access to everything in GRASS GIS, use GRASS GIS directly. QGIS GRASS Plugin will help you transition back and forth. A lot of people are using this workflow.

This was a general answer which seems appropriate now. If you have specific issues with using QGIS and GRASS GIS together, I suggest you to search the existing questions first and if this doesn't help, ask another one.

Comment: I think the question is far more simple than this. Parallax has downloaded the QGIS 2.12, it comes in processing with GRASS 7 tools, none of them work. How to make them work within QGIS? They are not asking for all tools in GRASS they are asking about 1 specific tool in processing that does not run (neither does the entire toolbox).

Comment: @Ifyoudonotknow-justGIS - According to one of the devs in [this forum](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.qgis.user/34241), GRASS 7 is somewhat supported in the 32bit OSGeo4W installer and will eventually be supported in 64bit. Perhaps test it on the 32bit version?

Answer (score 0):

GRASS is a standalone GIS. There are some features you can use in QGIS, if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: yes you are right but it is possible to [integrate](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/3rdParty) and [use](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/grass_integration/grass_integration.html) external applications in QGIS.

Comment: @parallax is correct. I am very surprised we have no answer to this.