# Use GRASS functions in QGIS that are not available in processing toolbox

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis, flow-accumulation

QGIS contains many Grass functions but not all. I want to use r.accumulate in QGIS but there is no tool available for it.

[image]

Is there a way to use these GRASS functions in QGIS directly or with pyQgis or doing a subprocess call?

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280813/compute-flow-accumulation-only-from-flow-direction

Comment: That tells about non-QGIS options, I am looking for QGIS solutions only